# Python file empty after unexpected laptop shutdown in Spyder in Windows

Tags: python, windows, crash, spyder, recover

I wrote a long and awesome code, but my laptop shutdown for some reasons, and when I start my laptop again, and opened my file. It was empty, but

This size  of the file is still the same. When I open my file in Spyder, it is empty but when I open the same file in Notepad++, `NULNULNUL` is showing like a lot of times.

Does spyder save the file in temporary files or something? Any way to recover the file? The file size is still same, so maybe some hope is there?

It took me weeks to write this code, I REALLY NEED THIS.

Comment: The file isn't empty. It apparently contains a stream of bytes with the value 0 exclusively. You can verify this by opening the file in a hex editor. Chances of recovering the previous contents are slim. The question on how to do this is off-topic here.

Comment: How to do this is off-topic? That is the most important thing dude.

Comment: Just because it's important to you, doesn't make it on-topic. See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We're very sorry for the problems Spyder has caused you. To fix this issue, we're going to add support for [autosave functionality](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/7660) in Spyder 4 (to be released in 2019).

Besides, this is going to be available publicly available since our second beta for Spyder.

Comment: its 2021 and I faced the same issue, seems like that feature never came